# bzlmod: dealing with external dependencies with no MODULE.bazel

Tags: bazel, bzlmod

I would like to use bzlmod as I am in the process of splitting a project into different modules and thought it would be a great way to solve the transitive dependencies.

However, not all project have yet a MODULE.bazel file (e.g. [grpc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc)), so the question is: **is it possible to add an external dependency that doesn't have a MODULE.bazel to the module system so that everything works fine if I reuse the new module**?

Comment: It seems like I can add non-module type of external dependencies within WORKSPACE.bzlmod, however I am getting issues when trying to add grpc and calling `grpc_deps()` and `grpc_extra_deps()`: `ERROR: /home/tfprime/.cache/bazel/_bazel_tfprime/040b7af43487855bbb11cfcfc4b9d95d/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/BUILD:92:6: no such package '@local_config_cc//': The repository '@local_config_cc' could not be resolved: Repository '@local_config_cc' is not defined and referenced by '@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain'`

Comment: I could see recently there was an ask on grpc for bzlmod as mentioned here https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/9559

Comment: Thank you. I've seen it too, I am just looking for a temporary solution that still uses bzlmod, otherwise I will keep using the old system until then which is unfortunate.